OrionLx+ Delay time syntax
What are other syntax for delay time in Orionlx+
I tried, busy wait loop, and os.execute. We are trying to control two line devices and the last devices that detected a tripping should be turned off after sometime We need to have a syntax for time delay for it to activate.
